# Regex for mark scheme

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am developing some node js code to parse pdf exam papers and march schemes. I am using regular expressions to convert the mark scheme into JSON.

I need a regEx for capturing both the `(a)/(b)/(i)` and everything up until the next `(a)/(b)/(i)`

A sample of the mark scheme:

```
(a) (iii) Separation of solid
Filter to obtain solid/precipitate
Requires realisation that solid is filtered off.
Solid may be stated within in ‘removal of water’
Removal of water
Dry (solid)
OR Evaporate (water/solution/liquid)
2 ALLOW
Removal of water
Evaporate/ distil water/solution/liquid 
IGNORE ‘distil’ if product OR H2 is distilled
Collection of remaining solid 
Requires realisation that solid remains
IGNORE ‘Leave to crystallise’ (already solid)
(a) (iv) Formula
```

in here I would want to capture the (a) and everything up to the next (a) and the (iii) and everything up to the (a) etc.

Here is my (failed) attempt https://regex101.com/r/QetW3f/1

Sorry for my awful explanation.

Comment: Try something like `/\(([a-z]+)\)\s+\(([ixvclmd]+)\)([^(]*(?:\((?![a-z]+\)\s+\([ixvclmd]+\))[^(]*)*)/gi`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dlESTV/1).

Comment: This was brilliant, thank you so much! Your expression has actually simplified my task a lot, would it be difficult to also capture numbers?

Comment: I do not think that part is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
/\(([a-z]+)\)\s+\(([ixvclmd]+)\)([^(]*(?:\((?![a-z]+\)\s+\([ixvclmd]+\))[^(]*)*)/gi
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dlESTV/1). Details:

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `([a-z]+)` - Group 1: one or more lowercase ASCII letters
- `\)` - `)` char
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `([ixvclmd]+)` - Group 2: one or more chars from the set
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `([^(]*(?:\((?![a-z]+\)\s+\([ixvclmd]+\))[^(]*)*)` - Group 3:

  - `[^(]*` - zero or more chars other than `(`
  - `(?:\((?![a-z]+\)\s+\([ixvclmd]+\))[^(]*)*` - zero or more occurrences of

    - `\((?![a-z]+\)\s+\([ixvclmd]+\))` - a `(` char not followed with one or more lowercase ASCII letters, `)`, one or more whitespaces, `(`, one or more chars from the `ixvclmd` set, `)`
    - `[^(]*` - zero or more chars other than `(`